# Dynamic memory allocation to char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have given the array size manually as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char buffer[1024];
    strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
    ...
}
```

But if the data passed in the argument exceeds this size, it <s>may</s> will create problems.

Is this the correct way to allocate memory dynamically?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int length;
    char *buffer;
    length = sizeof(argv[1]); //or strlen(argv[1])?
    buffer = (char*)malloc(length*sizeof(char *));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?  If you're working in C++, using `malloc()` is generally misguided (and raw `char *` is also not a good idea).  If you're working in C, you don't need the C++ tag.  In fact, don't dual-tag the question — they are two distinct languages.

Comment: As to your question "use `sizeof()` or `strlen()`",  using `strlen(argv[1])+1` will work as you want it to (and using `sizeof` will generally not allocate enough memory).  Bigger question, why do you need a copy of the data that `argv[1]` points at?

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` tells you the size of `char*`.  You want `strlen` instead

```
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Error - insufficient arguments\n");
    return 1;
}
length=strlen(argv[1]);
buffer = (char*)malloc(length+1); // cast required for C++ only
```

I've suggested a few other changes here

- you need to add an extra byte to `buffer` for the null terminator
- you should check that the user passed in an `argv[1]`
- `sizeof(char *)` is incorrect when calculating storage required for a string.  A C string is an array of `char`s so you need `sizeof(char)`, which is guaranteed to be 1 so you don't need to multiply by it

Alternatively, if you're running on a Posix-compatible system, you could simplify things and use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) instead:

```
buffer = strdup(argv[1]);
```

Finally, make sure to `free` this memory when you're finished with it

```
free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
length= strlen(argv[1]) //not sizeof(argv[1]);
```

and

```
//extra byte of space is to store Null character.    
buffer = (char*)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Since `sizeof(char)` is always one, you can also use this:

```
  buffer = (char*)malloc(length+1);
```

Comment: If C: a cast of malloc is not needed and the `sizeof(char)` is also redundant, because it is `1`.

Comment: @pzaenger yes agreed , written in general way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use `std::string` and let C++ do the work for you

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer = argv[1];
}
```

but if you want to do it the hard way then this is correct

```
int main()
{
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
}
```

Don't forget to +1 for the null terminator used in C style strings.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can do this to get your arguements in a nice data structure.

`const std::vector<std::string>(argv, argv + argc)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you use C++ I think it's better to use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Secondly, you're malloc size is false : `buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);` because you allocate a char buffer not a char* buffer.

thirdly, you must allocate 1 byte more for the end of your string and store '\0'.

Finally, sizeof get only the size of the type not a string, you must use strlen for getting string size.

Comment: In C++, it's even better not to use `new` but to use `std::string`.

Comment: I think it depends of what you want to do with it, if it's for storing a string, of course std::string do the job, but for an array which is not necessary a string, I prefere manage it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an extra byte to hold the terminating null byte of the string:

```
length=sizeof(argv[1]) + 1;
```

Then it should be OK.

Comment: sizeof is not OK in this context

Comment: @David Elliman The type of `argv[1]` is `char*`.  `sizeof(char*)` tells you the size of a pointer rather than the length of the string it points to.